# creating no.of display ids for eglgetdisplay

Tags: opengl-es, egl

currently iam creating display for my opengl application by caling eglgetdisplay with the parameter EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY.
if want to create more than one display in that case which parameter i can pass through eglgetdisplay becoz if with EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY it will get default id.

Comment: That's not platform independent as the parameter type `NativeDisplayType` already implies. So, this can be different on every platform. Just look at how `NativeDisplayType` is defined on your target platforms and supply each with the correct arguments.

Comment: What kind of device are you working with? Does it actually have more than one display?

Comment: iam working with opengl. for rendering primitives with the help of EGL iam creating display. if iam able to create one display means i can create more than display right???? but iam not getting how to create morethan one display

Comment: @SameemShaik like I said, it depends on the system you are running on, for some Linux implementations for example you would just pass the XServer display name as a string, like I said, it depends.

Answer (score 1):

A display corresponds to a physical screen which is the *default display*. Whenever `eglGetDisplay()` is called with `EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY` display type, a connection to this *default display* is returned. One will obtain connection to same default display even when such call is made in different applications because there is only one *default display*.

If you working on X11 or Wayland windowing system then `EGL_PLATFORM_X11_SCREEN_KHR`, `KHR_platform_wayland` extensions allow to obtain corresponding display. In that case `eglGetPlatformDisplay()` with parameter `EGL_PLATFORM_X11_KHR` or `EGL_PLATFORM_WAYLAND_KHR` will return corresponding display connections.

Please look at the extensions:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_platform_x11.txt
https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_platform_wayland.txt